# Proving the differentiation of distributions formula

Tags: integration, induction, solution-verification, distribution-theory

> Prove by induction that the differentiation of distributions is defined by the following integration-by-parts formula: For any distribution $f$ and a “nice” function $\varphi$, we have
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ \partial^{m}f(x) \ \varphi (x) = (-1)^{|m|} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ f(x) \ \partial^{m}\varphi (x)$$

This is what I have done

$1)$ Base case $m=0$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ \partial^{0}f(x) \ \varphi (x) = (-1)^{|0|} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ f(x) \ \partial^{0}\varphi (x) \Rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ f(x) \ \varphi (x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ f(x) \ \varphi (x)$$

OK.

$2)$ Induction hypothesis: the statement holds for $m$ (i.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ \partial^{m}f(x) \ \varphi (x) = (-1)^{|m|} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ f(x) \ \partial^{m}\varphi (x)$ holds).

$3)$ Induction step: show that the statement holds for  $m+1$. The trick is integrating by parts

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \  \partial^{m+1}f(x) \ \varphi (x) =  \partial^{m}f(x) \ \varphi (x)+(-1)\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \  \partial^{m}f(x) \ \partial \varphi (x) $$

Applying integration by parts $m$ times one gets

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \  \partial^{m+1}f(x) \ \varphi (x) =$$  $$=\partial^{m}f(x) \ \varphi (x)-\partial^{m-1}f(x) \ \partial \varphi (x) +...+(-1)^{|m+1|}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} dx \ f(x) \ \partial^{m+1} \varphi (x) $$

So we see that to finish our proof we need $\partial^{m}f(x) \ \varphi (x)-\partial^{m-1}f(x) \ \partial \varphi (x) +...$ to vanish. But how can we mathematically justify this? I guess it has to do with assuming boundary conditions. If that is the case, could do please explain me how to do so?

Besides I did not have to use the induction hypothesis. This has never happened to me before while using induction. I guess we need it to show $\partial^{m}f(x) \ \varphi (x)-\partial^{m-1}f(x) \ \partial \varphi (x) +...=0$?

Comment: The formula is not explained by integrating by parts because the functional $\langle f,\phi\rangle$ is not an integral.  Instead, we have by definition $\langle f',\phi\rangle =-\langle f,\phi'\rangle$.  Now, apply an induction proof.

Comment: @MarkViola Oh I now see $\langle f',\phi\rangle =-\langle f,\phi'\rangle$ is a definition. Then a proof would not apply. Or are you referring to another formula?

Comment: It is the definition of the distributional derivative.  So, inductively we can easily show that $$\langle f^{(n)},\phi\rangle =(-1)^n\langle f,\phi^{(n)}\rangle$$

Comment: @MarkViola I am a bit confused after thinking about your first comment. You said $\langle f,\phi\rangle$ is not an integral. However I've studied that, by definition, it is indeed an integral (please see 'Functions and measures as distributions' section on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Basic_idea). I'd go for integration by parts to prove what you stated in your second comment but you suggest that is not the right approach. My question then is: if $\langle f,\phi\rangle$ is not an integral, how is it defined then?

Comment: Note the passage in that section that reads "As described next, there are straightforward mappings from both locally integrable functions and Radon measures to corresponding distributions, but not all distributions can be formed in this manner."   In your question, $f$ is ANY distribution.  If $f$ is locally integrable, then for a suitable test function $\phi$, $\langle f,\phi\rangle =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\phi(x)\,dx$.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks for the clarification. So in this problem we're certainly assuming a 'nice' function $\phi$ so that $\langle f,\phi\rangle =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\phi(x)\,dx$

Comment: Should we go for integration by parts then? If that is not what you have in mind, what approach should we use?

Comment: You can do so if $f$ is also integrable.